# Javascript : Run client side EXE by CHROME

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, activex, npapi

I want to run a client side exe by using Javasript.

I tried the below code .. it works fine in IE.

**Code:**

```
function myFunction(){
   WshShell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell"); 
   WshShell.run("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"); 
}
```

***but i want to work that code in Chrome***.

I have search this thing in Google and found we can access the client side files by using **`NPAPI plugin`** 
can any one give me a idea about this

Where to download..? and what is the JScript code for NPAPI plugin to run the EXE.?

**Note :** Please don't comment like "this is Security violation" OR "you are not suppose to do this".

My application is **Intranet application and my exe is known EXE** so please help me on this.

Comment: for interest sake, what does the exe do?

Comment: You wouldn't download an NPAPI plugin to do this, you'd write one. It's wildly unlikely that anyone has written and distributed an existing plugin to do this because a generic plugin that could launch any binary would (as you appear to know) be a *terrible* idea. You'd need to write something custom for your case, that verifies the origin and the binary. But as the duplicate question points out, writing an NPAPI plugin to do this in Chrome would not be a good idea since it would stop working quite soon.